# how I fix problem on my cloth

Tags: cloth-simulation

at the sleeve height and in various places the Mesh do not close. can anyone tell me why or what to do?
this is the project [image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At first you should decrease Object collision Distance because the cloth is very far away from the model and disable Self collisions, which can cause problems.

Next, I think you just haven't enough material to cover all the body.  Why don't you increase surface area of cloth?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure your normals are not simply flipped. select all and Recalculate Normals (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>)

If that doesn't fix it, Select all of the edges bridging the gap and Collapse them (<kbd>M</kbd> -> Collapse).

This should close up your holes.